# .net core Session state not maintaining while accessing site from cordova (android/ios)

Tags: angular, .net-core

Server side: .net core web api.
Client side: angular 8.

Session Id keep changing in each request while accessing the asp.net core web api application from cordova (android/ios).

Session works fine when i try to access from chrome/firefox browser, but it's not working if I installed the app in android/ios device.

Comment: Where are you hosting your api? Did you enable sticky sessions?

Comment: at the moment in iis